# clarification/when/where to use super in django/python

Tags: python, django, forms, models, super

Actually we know `super` is used to find the "parent class" and return its object, something like/using `self.__class__.__mro__`

What I was confused about is *when to use it exactly?*

Suppose we have a Example model code as below

**version_1**

```
class Example(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    age  = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, **args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(Example, self).save(self, **args, **kwargs)
        obj.name = "name changed"
        obj.age = "age changed"
        return obj
```

**version_2**

```
class Example(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    age  = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, **args, **kwargs):
        self.name = "name changed"
        self.age = "age changed"
        obj = super(Example, self).save(self, **args, **kwargs)
        return obj
```

so as we can observe above

In **version_1** I have called `super` first and done modifications to fields and returned the obj

In **version_2** I had modified the fields and after that called super and returned obj

So what happens when super is called before and after modification of fields?

Finally what i want to know/confirm is

- Where/why exactly super is used in django forms/models.
- What is the exact concept of using them in django / python (if I understood this wrong).

Comment: I don't get what you are asking. Obviously calling `super` before means that the parent-class wont know of that information and you'll end up overwriting the result(which may or may not be what you want), if you call it after then the method is able to use the information you just set(which may or may not be what you want). The result completely depends on the specific situation.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Thanks for ur reply, i am sorry can u please be more specific about the words `the method is able to use the information you just set` ? I got the answer that if we call before the parent methods or we want will be overriden, but not clear about `after` i mean the scenario on `how it uses the info`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your `Example` class is a subclass of `Model`. That means, that `Example` inherits all functions from `Model`.

Look at the following:

```
class Example():
    pass

example = Example()
#let's try to save it
example.save()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Example instance has no attribute 'save'
```

Now with inheritance.

```
class Parent():
    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        print "saving now"

class Example(Parent):
    pass

example = Example()
#since Example has no save method, it inherits the Parent's save method.
example.save()
"saving now"
```

If you override the save() method in your Example class, the Parent's save method will not be called.

```
   class Example(Parent):
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print "i know how to save on my own now"

   example = Example()
   example.save()
   "i know how to save on my own now"
```

If you choose to call super, you are calling the Parent's save function together with your own implementation of save().

```
   class Example(Parent):
         def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
              super(Example, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
              print "i know how to save on my own now"

   example = Example()
   example.save()
   "saving now" #from parent
   "i know how to save on my own" #from example
```

The same applies to all of djangos classes you inherit from. In fact, the implementation is more complex. You can take a look at the Model definition here on [github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py).

If you feel thrilled, you can dive into the django ORM with this [talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgV39DlmZ2U)

Answer (score 5):

I believe this question in not Django specific, therefore I will try to explain it in a generic way.

The practicality of super is that you do not need to specify which base class is to be called (this can also be a downside because the mro defines what base class is called).

I use super to create mixins (there is an excellent answer on SO that describes what a mixin is). An example that uses super:

```
class LemonMixin(object):
    def tastes_like(self):
        return super(LemonMixin, self).tastes_like() + ' and lemon'

class Cola(object):
    def tastes_like(self):
        return 'sugar'

class ColaLemon(LemonMixin, Cola):
    pass

drink = ColaLemon()
drink.tastes_like()  # returns 'sugar and lemon'
```

The mixin is agnostic of the aplied class so it can use super to use the mro to call a base class.

When to call super is totally up to you. If you, for example, want to check for security you call super after the security checks. If you want to fire an event when something finished, you may want to call super before firing the event. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You call `super`:

- first if the parent's method fills attributes you need in your treatment
- last if you change the value of some attributes and want to apply the parent's method treatment with those new values

In conclusion, when you wanna change the implementation of a parent method:

- Go to the  parent's method implementation. Check what is done. Your IDE probably eases the job of retrieving the parent implementation, otherwise go to your Django install directory, then to `/lib/python/site-packages/django` and find the implementation by yourself.
- According to your need (=use an attribute generated by the parent method OR change the value of an attribute used by the parent method) use super before OR after your custom code.